# Besides Floyd–Steinberg dithering, any other ways to dither the images?

Tags: image, image-processing

I am wondering besides Floyd–Steinberg dithering, any famous dithering algorithm exists?

Comment: Here’s an overview showing also some more modern approaches than what is discussed in the answers below: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/355/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some other error diffusion algorithms, the [Wikipedia page on dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Algorithms) gives a good list and images to compare the algorithms:

- Floyd–Steinberg dithering only diffuses the error to neighbouring
  pixels. This results in very fine-grained dithering.
- Jarvis, Judice, and Ninke dithering diffuses the error also to pixels one step further away. The dithering is coarser, but has
  fewer visual artifacts. It is slower than Floyd–Steinberg dithering
  because it distributes errors among 12 nearby pixels instead of 4
  nearby pixels for Floyd–Steinberg.
- [Stucki dithering](https://web.archive.org/web/20120815114111/http://sekal.ics.p.lodz.pl/%7Eandrey/html/po/doc/org/plant/kzpif/filters/dithering/Stucki.html) is based on the above, but is slightly faster. Its output tends to be clean and sharp.
- Burkes dithering is a simplified form of Stucki dithering that is faster, but less clean than Stucki dithering.
- Sierra dithering is based on Jarvis dithering, but it's faster while giving similar results.
- Two-row Sierra is the above method modified by Sierra to improve its speed.
  Filter Lite is an algorithm by Sierra that is much simpler and faster than Floyd–Steinberg, while still yielding similar (according to Sierra, better) results.
- Atkinson dithering resembles Jarvis dithering and Sierra dithering, but it's faster. Another difference is that it doesn't diffuse the entire quantization error, but only three quarters. It tends to preserve detail well, but very light and dark areas may appear blown out.
- Even toned screening is a patented modification of Floyd–Steinberg dithering intended to reduce visual artifacts, in particular to produce more even dot patterns in highlights and shadows.

Unfortunately, there are no details there, you'll have to google for the algorithms to get further information about the diffusion tables etc. <strike>I'll try to edit and update the list and offer some links.</strike>

EDIT: [This text file](https://gist.github.com/robertlugg/f0b618587c2981b744716999573c5b65) [(original links is dead)](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/ImageProcessing/DHALF.TXT) seems to have good explanations and diffusion tables for most of the listed algorithms.

Comment: I have archived the text file referenced at https://gist.github.com/robertlugg/f0b618587c2981b744716999573c5b65

Comment: A good list,  but the “slower”/“faster” demarcation is not really relevant. All of these methods are really fast, the differences are really minor. Other dithering techniques are iterative, significantly more expensive, and quite a bit better than the ones listed here.